# Make space to get occupied when bootstrap navbar collapses

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm trying to make my page fill the space when my navbar collapses in mobile view but it seems to leave the space empty(Instead of the images beside it filling up). The navbar also tends to push the items downwards.I initially used bootstraps grid but switched to css grid(thought this was the problem). Any suggestions will help thanks.

my code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
}

.mens {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.bars {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
}

.pics {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=320" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <title>gridstest</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">


    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="mens border border-primary m-2">
        <nav class="nav-navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand p-1 fw-bolder " href="#"> BRAND</a>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column m-1">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">OPTION X</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">OPTION X</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">OPTION X/a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">OPTION X</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">OPTION X</a>
              </li>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>

      <div class="bars border border-secondary m-2">
        <div class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight ">
          <a class="navbar-link text-dark ms-auto p-2" href="#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20"
              height="20" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path
                d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z" />
            </svg></a>
          <a class="navbar-link p-2 text-dark" href="#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20"
              fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-bag" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path
                d="M8 1a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.5 2.5V4h-5v-.5A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 8 1zm3.5 3v-.5a3.5 3.5 0 1 0-7 0V4H1v10a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V4h-3.5zM2 5h12v9a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V5z" />
            </svg></a>
          <a class="navbar-link p-2 text-dark" href="#"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20"
              fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path
                d="M8 8a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6zm2-3a2 2 0 1 1-4 0 2 2 0 0 1 4 0zm4 8c0 1-1 1-1 1H3s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4zm-1-.004c-.001-.246-.154-.986-.832-1.664C11.516 10.68 10.289 10 8 10c-2.29 0-3.516.68-4.168 1.332-.678.678-.83 1.418-.832 1.664h10z" />
            </svg></a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="pics border border-danger border-3 m-2">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-6 relate">
            <a class="ripple" href="#"><img class="img-fluid shadow" src="https://via.placeholder.com/3648.jpg">
              <div class="bottom-left ">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Buy</button>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-6 relate">
            <a class="ripple" href="#"><img class="img-fluid shadow" src="https://via.placeholder.com/3648.jpg">
              <div class="bottom-left">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Buy now</button>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 relate">
            <a class="ripple" href="#"><img class="img-fluid shadow" src="https://via.placeholder.com/3648.jpg">
              <div class="bottom-left">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Buy now</button>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-6  relate">
            <a class="ripple" href="#"><img class="img-fluid shadow" src="https://via.placeholder.com/3648.jpg">
              <div class="bottom-left">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Buy now</button>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-6  relate">
            <a class="ripple" href="#"><img class="img-fluid shadow" src="https://via.placeholder.com/3648.jpg">
              <div class="bottom-left">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Buy now</button>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-6  relate">
            <a class="ripple" href="#"><img class="img-fluid shadow" src="https://via.placeholder.com/3648.jpg">
              <div class="bottom-left">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Buy now</button>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>


        </div>


        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-6  relate">
            <a class="ripple" href="#"><img class="img-fluid shadow" src="https://via.placeholder.com/3648.jpg">
              <div class="bottom-left">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Buy now</button>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-6  relate">
            <a class="ripple" href="#"><img class="img-fluid shadow" src="https://via.placeholder.com/3648.jpg">
              <div class="bottom-left">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Buy now</button>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>


        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-6  relate">
            <a class="ripple" href="#"><img class="img-fluid shadow" src="https://via.placeholder.com/3648.jpg">
              <div class="bottom-left">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Buy now</button>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-6  relate">
            <a class="ripple" href="#"><img class="img-fluid shadow" src="https://via.placeholder.com/3648.jpg">
              <div class="bottom-left">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Buy now</button>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>



        </div>





      </div>







    </div>




  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The image:
[image]

Comment: Please could you check if fixing the viewport will fix the issue.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Are you saying that once the Nav collapses it leaves a white-space before your remaining content? Thanks if you can add any more information or even a screen-shot.

Comment: @CuteCodeRob Yea. Ive added the screenshot. Also the rest of the content should occupy the white space after it collapses

Comment: When I try your code I get no space from the Nav and no space inside your red border. The green buttons appear directly beneat the images and the images are at the top of the box. You do have a typo in your menu though. bracket missing at the end of one of the options.

Comment: Ive must have missed the bracket while pasting the code.I use the wrapper for styling the contents inside, could that be the problem? I want to change the bootstrap manner of pushing the content down yes its working normally. would you suggest coding my own navbar fro scratch? @CuteCodeRob

Comment: @CuteCodeRob Maybe its the layout code of my page(separate column for the navbar) but when inspecting on mobile view when it collapses id expect the images to occupy that space. Now not sure if its the layout or the navbar

Comment: In this situation it can be best to start from the beginning. I don't mean delete everything. Add a second Nav underneath your original. Go slow, get it working then delete your original Nav. I should do all this by copying what you need from GetBootstrap Docs. Ensure that you are on the right docs for your Bootstrap version (3, 4, 5). One thing is for sure.... Your .wrapper and .mens could easily be messing with Bootstrap. #section to .Container to .Row should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238332/discussion-between-cute-code-rob-and-grim).